# gcc problem with explicit template instantiation?

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

It is my understanding that either a declaration or typedef of a specialization ought to cause a template class to be instantiated, but this does not appear to be happening with gcc. E.g. I have a template class, template class Foo {};

I write

```
  class Foo<double>;
```

or

```
typedef Foo<double> DoubleFoo;
```

but after compilation the symbol table of the resulting object file does not contain the members of Foo.

If I create an *instance*:

```
Foo<double> aFoo;
```

then of course the symbols are all generated.

Has anyone else experienced this and/or have an explanation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax for explicit instantiation is

```
template class Foo<double>;
```

See C++03 §14.7.2.

Hoping the functions get generated and linked, but not stripped after creating, but not using, an instance (the most minimal implicit instantiation), is quite a gamble.

Comment: I think Potatoswatter is on to something here. I have never heard of such a use for typedef. That is only for shorthanding types, and never instantiates anything.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I'm not sure where I picked up that misinformation about typedefs. I was on the right track with declaration but left off the crucial 'template' keyword.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about *implicit instantiation*. But that does only happen if the completenes of the class type would affect semantics of the program.

In your case, the class type doesn't need to be complete because the type you typedef can stay incomplete (class body is not needed, so there is no need to instantiate it). To illustrate, you can also say `typedef class MyFunnyThing type;` in a statement of its own, without ever defining that class anywhere.

If you create an object, the type of it has to be complete, and so the class template then is implicitly instantiated. Please note that implicit instantiation of a class template will not implicitly instantiate the member function or static datamember definitions, unless they are explicitly used elsewhere.

Also, to declare a specialization of a class-template, *the whole point* is to *prevent* an instantiation to happen, to tell the compiler "don't instantiate, because later i specialize it explicitly". The declaration if your specialization also misses a `template<>` in front of it.