# What is the best way to handle a collection of derived objects in a derived class

Tags: c++, collections, derived-class

Imagine I have a class 'BaseA' that contains a collection of items 'ItemA'.
Now I want to extend 'BaseA' to add extra capabilities, so I derive 'DerivedA' from 'BaseA'.
 One characteristic of 'DerivedA' is that it has to handle more sophisticated 'DerivedITemA' items instead of 'ItemA' ones.

```
class BaseA {
protected:
    vector<ItemA> x;
    void m1(int i) { x.m1(i); }
};

class ItemA {
protected:
    void m1(int i) { ... }
};

class DerivedItemA : public ItemA {
    void m2(int i) { ... }
};
```

Now I would like to handle something of this sort:

```
class DerivedA : public BaseA {
    vector<DerivedItemA> x;
    void m2(int i) { x[i].m2(); }
};
```

I.e. have my Derived class handle derived items. The above definition of x is incorrect as it clashes with the one in BaseA. But the idea is I want to be able to reuse all methods in BaseA that handle x as long as they deal with ItemA elements and have the extended methods in DerivedA to handle the extra intricacies of DerivedItemA type of data

Any suggestion? My current thoughts are in the lines of defining a new datatype for x (VectorOfItemA for instance) and derive from it VectorOfDerivedItemA. I wonder if there is a simpler / better solution.

Thanks

Comment: "The above definition of x is incorrect as it clashes with the one in BaseA." No, the `x` in the derived class would hide the `x` of the base class. That is, functions in the base class would still operate on `BaseA::x` whereas functions in the derived class operate on `DerivedA::x` (using unqualified-ids).

Comment: How are you adding elements to the vector?

Comment: What is your intended usage? To have one collection of `ItemA` or `DerivedItemA` objects that are polymorphic? if so, you need to store *pointers* to your objects (ideally, smart pointers), but as-presented it is not clear exactly what you want.

Comment: After reading the question I have a few points of clarification: What's the relationship between `ItemA` and `DerivedItemA`? Are you perhaps using inheritance to reuse rather than to extend/substitute? In a `DerivedA` will *all* items being stored be of type `DerivedItemA`? Are you using inheritance to reuse in the `BaseA` and `DerivedA` relationship?

Comment: To clarify, vector x will contain either all elements of type ItemA in BaseA instantiations or all elements of DerivedItemA in DerivedA instantiations. There is no need to mix. The intended use of inheritance here is to extend functionality. I.e. DerivedItemA follow a ISA relationship with ItemA, but do have extra attributes/methods etc.

Comment: Generally speaking while `ISA` has been historically used to justify inheritance, it's not always the full story. You usually want something where inheritance represents substitution, and the full interface is declared in the base class (to avoid any need for casting). A concrete example of what `ItemA` and `DerivedItemA` really are would really help (including why `DerivedItemA` has methods that aren't part of `ItemA`'s interface).

Comment: @Mark B : My concrete case is the following: BaseA represents a low level representation of a program (SimProgram). ItemA is a instruction that contains enough fields and functionality to be simulable. DerivedA is an extension of SimProgram where there are extra methods to manipulate/modify the program. DerivedItemA is an extension of SimInstr that contains extra fields/methods to help in this program modifications

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to have pointers in your vectors in order to handle this. I'm a little confused what value to pass to m1 and m2 since i appears to be an index, but here's my guess:

```
class BaseA {
protected:
    vector<ItemA*> x;
    void m1(int i) { x[i]->m1(i); }
};

class ItemA {
protected:
    void m1(int i) { ... }
};

class DerivedItemA : public ItemA {
    void m2(int i) { ... }
};

class DerivedA : public BaseA {
    vector<DerivedItemA*> y; //don't shadow the base class vector!
    void m2(int i) { y[i]->m2(i); }
};
```

Then, when you add an item in DerivedA, add it to both x and y. That way BaseA can do it's thing to the pointer in x and DerivedA can do its thing on the pointer in y.

Edit: you'll also need to provide a virtual method for adding items otherwise you might get things added to BaseA.x that don't get added to DerivedA.y.

Comment: I want the methods in BaseA to act over the same data items than the methods in DerivedA, so I would try to eliminate the two copies x/y  and see if one can do. If the constructor of DerivedA populates vector with DerivedItemA elements instead of from ItemA ones then when accessing x in DerivedA one would find that is accessing a vector<ItemA*> so accesses to methods of DerivedItemA would have to be down-casted to DerivedItemA* every single time :(

Comment: @metalhead, 1. Who will own objects? 2. There is no need to have two vectors in DerivedA - [for example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/44DC6x).

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use Curiously Recurring Template Pattern - [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0666778779c36500)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Item
{
    void m1(int i)
    {
        cout << "m1(" << i << ")" << endl;
    }
};
struct DerivedItem : Item
{
    void m2(int i)
    {
        cout << "m2(" << i << ")" << endl;
    }
};

template<typename Derived>
struct IBase
{
    void m1(int i)
    {
        for(auto &&z : static_cast<Derived*>(this)->x)
        {
            z.m1(i);
        }
    }
};
template<typename Derived>
struct IDerivedBase: IBase<Derived>
{
    void m2(int i)
    {
        for(auto &&z : static_cast<Derived*>(this)->x)
        {
            z.m2(i);
        }
    }
};

struct Base : IBase<Base>
{
    vector<Item> x;
};
struct DerivedBase : IDerivedBase<DerivedBase>
{
    vector<DerivedItem> x;
};

int main()
{
    Base b;
    b.x.resize(3);
    DerivedBase d;
    d.x.resize(1);

    b.m1(11);
    d.m1(22);
    d.m2(33);
}
```

Output is:

```
m1(11)
m1(11)
m1(11)
m1(22)
m2(33)
```

> Vector will contain either all elements as ItamA in BaseA instantiations or all elements of DerivedItemA in DerivedA instantiaions. There is no need to mix.

There is no any mix at this approach:

- **Base** has only vector<**Item**> providing **m1** method
- **DerivedBase** has only vector<**DerivedItem**> providing **m1** and **m2** methods.

---

However, without knowing real usage pattern - it is hard to guess what you need. Maybe for your case two standalone vectors would be enough:

```
vector<Item> x1;
vector<DerivedItem> x2;
```

and just define stand-alone functions for them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you own all the classes? If so, you can refactor into a template base class instead.

```
template <typename ITEM>
class BaseT {
protected:
    vector<ITEM> x;
    void m1(int i) { x[i].m1(); }
};

typedef BaseT<ItemA> BaseA;

class DerivedA: public BaseT<DerivedItemA> {
    void m2(int i) { x[i].m2(); }
};
```

If you intend to re-use code that takes `BaseA` to also accept a `DerivedA`, then you may need to modify them to be template functions/classes as well.

Otherwise, you will need some kind of "polymorphic" base object for the vector. You can look at [Retrieve data from heterogeneous std::list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796341/retrieve-data-from-heterogeneous-stdlist) (or my follow up question: [unique_ptr member, private copy constructor versus move constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821535/unique-ptr-member-private-copy-constructor-versus-move-constructor)) for one such approach.

---

As an alternative to a polymorphic item, you can define an interface for your base.

```
class BaseI {
protected:
    virtual void m1(int) = 0;
    //... other interfaces
public:
    virtual ~BaseI () {}
    //... other public interfaces
};

template <typename ITEM>
class BaseT : public BaseI {
protected:
    vector<ITEM> x;
    void m1(int i) { x[i].m1(); }
    //...implement the other interfaces
};

//...
```

Now, code that takes a `BaseA` needs to be refactored to take a `BaseI` instead. That new code will be able to accept a `DerivedA` as well.

Comment: Yes I own all the classes, but they are too big for my taste to make them templates. I also want to make them part of a library without exposing all the functionality in a header file

Comment: It is possible to use templates and still hide implementation details via explicit instantiation of the templates within the library non-header source files. However, you can follow the two links I added to my answer for some other ideas.

Comment: The header file can "forward declare" a template. The source file in the library can define the template and instantiate it for the objects that are relevant. In your case, `BaseA` and `DerivedA`. This technique doesn't work if you intend the library user to create their own derivations though.

Comment: There are lots of relevant SO posts on explicit template instantiation. Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738760/gcc-problem-with-explicit-template-instantiation